# what's the practical difference between google datastore nosql and google bigquery sql?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, nosql

I want to know how to evaluate one tool over another.

My major concern is as following:

In google datastore, we define 'kind'. Each 'entities' has 'properties'.
Then the datastore backends use those properties to index data for future query. The query itself use almost the same idea in SQL, though different syntax, to filter data and find what we want.
If you index every property, the index metadata would be even bigger than real data.

Google bigquery uses it's dialect of SQL. And it's fully managed so users don't have to worry about the scaling problem.

So my question is, what's the purpose of using nosql datastore, spending so many computing cycles and storage for indexes so that we could just query it like we naturally could in bigquery SQL database?

Please share with me your evaluation process. 
Share with me what's the missing piece in my understandings. 
Thanks.

Comment: This is off-topic for stack, maybe more on topic for Google Groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) But in general, you need to remember you cannot edit BigQuery once it's uploaded, so it cannot serve for the same kind of things as datastore can. Also, BigQuery is amazing at handling.... well... BIG data. For smaller data, datastore could actually be faster

Comment: that's a valid point. thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's off-topic. Seems like a valid question about when to use which tool.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The two services solve different problems.

**Datastore** is designed to support **transactional** workloads, such as the backend for a web application. It's optimized for small transactions that read or write a limited number of rows per operation, with strong consistency guarantees.

**BigQuery** is designed for **analytic** workloads. It's append-only, and it's optimized for queries that scan/filter/aggregate entire tables of data to get answers out of your data.

So the real question is: what problem are you trying to solve? If you're building a web app and need a backend, use Datastore. If you have piles of data that you want to query to get answers about how your business is performing, use BigQuery.

Finally, if you want to do both, you can use Datastore for your app, and then export to BigQuery for analysis:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. I didn't take the append-only nature into consideration at the beginning. Now I know better. In my company, I have different kinds of data, for example user's personal profile data. I am just doing some research on different tools, so I could solve different problem using appropriate one.

Comment: try both. queries in bigquery will be slow and painful as you need to wait and ping until the query finishes excution. that would be disastrous in a webapp using it as database.

Answer (score 0):

I think cloud datastore can be used as a backend where you will traditionally persist your application objects to . You mostly pick data from your datastore storage . While big query can be used to query your datasets from cloud datastore .  In today's analytics it becomes ideal to store a copy of your datastore data to big query this way you can easily get insights from your datastore from big query without bothering about querying your datastore ,knowing its query limitations .