# Order By and Group By in Google Datastore Node Query JS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to write a datastore query in NodeJS.

I want to order by timestamp but also only distinct unique ID's (no duplicates) and only retrieve the latest datastore item for each unique ID.

---

For example

```
USER_ID - TIMESTAMP
10      - 1000
10      - 500
5       - 10
5       - 1500
5       - 50
```

I want the query to result with

```
USER_ID - TIMESTAMP
10      - 1000
5       - 1500
```

---

What I've tried:

```
datastore.createQuery('example')
  .groupBy('USER_ID')
  .order('USER_ID')
  .order('TIMESTAMP')
```

But it returns the data ordered by `USER_ID`, not `TIMESTAMP`

---

*Here's a pastebin to help answer the question: https://pastebin.com/MQCibmiw*

Comment: You have this line `.order('USER_ID')` , which does the order by `USER_ID` .

Comment: If I remove that line, I receive an error telling me I must order by the group by column.

Comment: Can you try changing the sequence.. `datastore.createQuery('example') .order('TIMESTAMP', {descending: true,}) .groupBy('USER_ID') .order('USER_ID')`

Comment: What do you actually get back lets say from your example? (I ask as I do my work on python, so as to ensure sth is same.)

Comment: I get back from `createQuery` a query object. Then I run `runQuery(query)` which returns an array `[ results, metaData ]`.

Comment: @MatrixTai https://pastebin.com/MQCibmiw

Comment: Can you go to your Datastore -> Entitles -> Query by Gql, and type `select distinct on (USER_ID) * from "YOUR_TABLE" order by USER_ID, TIMESTAMP desc`. See if the data queried as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do the sort by timestamp yourself.  As previously mentioned, order by USER_ID takes priority, and it's needed because you are running a [distinct on](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-datastore-distinct-on-query-gql) query for the grouping.

Comment: I ended up doing this, I thought there would surely be a solution but if not, thats fine.

Comment: This is actually not an option for me as I need to query batches (currently implementing pagination), and filtering manually rather than within the query makes this not possible

Answer (score 0):

As Jim Morrison said, I don't think this is possible.

I filed a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117144871) on your behalf. Check if my understanding was correct and feel free to add as many details as you think is needed.

Meanwhile I think the only option you have is to order the TIMESTAMP "manually".

Comment: Thank you very much. I've made a reply to the thread you've created.

Comment: Answering to your reply there: Yes, this ordering for two columns it's what I meant with "double ordering", that's why I specified the max function or any way to get the same outcome. Also, even though I was quite sure this was not possible, I tried anyway with Node.js, Python and GQL without success (as expected). This is quite easy to do in SQL or BQ, but the way GQL is design I think it's not possible

Comment: Hm interesting.. makes me wonder why my company went with GQL :/

Comment: Datastore has its upsides and downsides if you compare them. You can read this [article](https://weidongzhou.wordpress.com/2017/06/10/google-cloud-sql-vs-cloud-datastore-vs-bigtable-vs-bigquery-vs-spanner/) where it's explained the differences between storage options in GCP and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723136/whats-the-practical-difference-between-google-datastore-nosql-and-google-bigque). Also you can use this [decision tree found](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) in GCP documentation

Comment: Google uses GQL for most of their services right.. surely they have come across the same need that I have. There must be a solution surely

Comment: No, Cloud SQL uses MySQL or PostgreSQL, Spanner uses NewSQL, BigQuery uses another interpretation of SQL language. For example, I tried to do this in BQ and it was possible (you can use Max function for example)

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense

Comment: Here you have an example of this query running in BigQuery (you can tinker a little bit with it if you feel like it by copying it in the BQ UI). [EXAMPLE](https://pastebin.com/VqFd5Ne5)